# Default Checked checkbox need to unchecked in angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript

Here my Components code there i am pushing all id's and binding into checked in checkbox

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.featureData.length; i++) {
    var user = this.featureData[i]
    this.feature_id = user.feature_id;
    this.datauser.push(this.feature_id);
}
```

Here my Html code  to binding data to checked box to checked

```
<div *ngIf="!!datauser?.length">
    <div class="ui test toggle checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox"  *ngFor="let data of datauser" [checked]="data == feature.feature_id"  (change)="addInSelectedFeatures(feature.Feature.feature_id)" [value]="feature.feature_id">
        <label></label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="ui test toggle checkbox" *ngIf="!(!!datauser?.length)">
    <input type="checkbox"  name="" (change)="addInSelectedFeatures(feature.Feature.feature_id)" [value]="feature.feature_id">
    <label></label>
</div>
```

Comment: What you expect 'data == feature.feature_id' from ?

Comment: What is `data` ?

Comment: data menaces it's references or object for datauser

Comment: Where does the `feature.feature_id` come from?

Comment: feature.feature_id  already had value if   data == feature.feature_id is both match the check box is checked like data=1 then  feature.feature_id=1 then it's checked

Comment: If you assign data=-1 all checkbox are unselected,Is this the real problem?, maybe you send more information or post sample in stackblitz

Comment: here can i upload screenshot of my problem

Comment: data=1 and feature.feature_id=1 or data=4 and feature.feature_id=4 any value if match with feature.feature_id then it's checked , i want unchecked which are checked but it's not availing to unchecked

Comment: May you show all your component’s code?

Answer (score 0):

In html attribute *checked* define checkbox initial value. Change of this attr don't change checkbox view.

In your case, maybe better use [(ngModel)]:

```
...
<input type="checkbox"
       *ngFor="let data of datauser"
       [checked]="data.id== feature.feature_id"
       [(ngModel)]="data.isChecked"
       (change)="onCheckboxValueChange(data, feature)">
...
```

Simple worked example:
app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { routerAnimation } from '../shared/index';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {

  onCheckboxValueChange(data){
    console.log(data);
  }

}
```

app.component.html

```
<input type="checkbox"
       *ngFor="let data of [{id: 1, isChecked: true }, {id: 2,isChecked: false }, {id: 3,isChecked: true }]"
       [checked]="data.isChecked == true"
       [(ngModel)]="data.isChecked"
       (change)="onCheckboxValueChange(data)">
```

Comment: what is isChecked ??

Comment: It’s a property in **data** object. ‘data = { id: number, isChecked: boolean}’. It’s property binded with checkbox with help of form directive [(ngModel)]. When checkbox change value data.isChecked change value too.

Comment: div *ngIf="!!datauser?.length">
                <div class="ui test toggle checkbox">
                  <input type="checkbox"  *ngFor="let data of datauser"  [(ngModel)]="data == feature.feature_id"    (change)="addInSelectedFeatures(feature.Feature.feature_id)" [value]="feature.feature_id">
                    <label></label>
                  </div> is this code will work

Comment: Use one way binding with ‘[ngModel]=“data == feature.feature_id”’. All other depends of code in your component

Comment: `(ngModelChange)` is Output callback when the value of checkbox is change

Comment: Read about binding in [angular guide](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ngmodel---two-way-binding-to-form-elements-with-ngmodel)

Comment: Hi Thanks Lvanes it's working i used [(ngModel)] it's working